# Google Speech to text API in web application

Tags: html, jsf, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I want to try Google Speech to text API in a JSF application (which for the client generates html). I tried to search, but there is no suitable resource available in the web. It is available for Java SE, but can't be converted to Java Web.

Can anyone guide me on how to use Google Speech to text API in a java web application developed using JSF?

Comment: Can you maybe provide some Google Speech API example/link that cannot be converted to "Java Web"?

Comment: If it cannot be converted to web in general, it cannot be converted to 'JSF'

Comment: In what can it be converted?

Comment: A web app that can transcript voice. So text can be then to controllers from ajax and process.